# Group the return results of mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I was almost exhausted tweaking the queries and finally thought of posting the question here to get the help. I have a mysql table as below. I am coding in Nodejs and accessing the database using jdbc connector.

```
name    subject class   score
Harry   science 8   60
John    Science 9   65
Harry   Maths   8   80
Harry   English 9   50
Mike    Maths   8   90
John    English 8   60
```

When I do my query, I need to get the result "grouped by name" and "class=8". I know that I can return all the results where "class=8" and then iterate through the result`s to form the below object. As my real database is quite complex, I want return result from mysql itself to be grouped as below. Can it be possible using mysql query? If not possible using query, what is the best and safest way to code in order to get the below format?

```
{
Harry:[{score:60, subject: science}, {score:80, subject: Maths}],
John:[{score:60, subject: English}],
Mike:[{score:90, subject: Maths}]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without considering the merits of the JSON syntax that you can complete in a timely manner using concat to concatenate strings as you like .. you can use group_concat to get all the results of a name on the same line .. group_concat is an aggregate function and you must use the group by to group in a suitable way

```
  select name, group_concat( concat(score, subject))
  from my_table
  where class ='8'
  group by name
```

Comment: Using this query, do we get all the results if there are some rows and columns with null values?

Comment: @bobby   explain better ...if  you need  also the null value  then you should manage the results  properly .. otherwise  .. filter the data selected  using where  your_col is not null so you don't get the null result

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. Actually, I have one more column called "teacher". However, all the teacher rows for now are empty. If I include "teacher" in above query, it is resulting in empty results. "group_concat( concat(score, subject, teacher))"....  Why is it happening so? How can I come out of this situation?

Comment: @Bobby   . I can produce answer  only based  on what you have write in question  .. i can't eval   info about  argument that i don't know. ..(anyway i think that the teacher shoul be a column and not a rows .. if is correctly stored . in db.. )   .. could be this is another answer .. so .. eval if my answer  id right or not .. and learn and eventually you can post a new proper question for others problems